# How to handle dependency injection with mvvmlight

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, mvvm-light, viewmodellocator

i've no clue how to inject a parameter in the constuctor call of the MainWindowViewModel. What i want is to register an instance of the current mainwindow (this) in the viewmodellocator. How can i accomplish this?

This is my situation in the viewmodellocator class:

```
public ViewModelLocator()
{
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

    //SimpleIoc.Default.Register<Window>();  //THIS IS NOT WORKING BECOUSE ITS A NEW INSTANCE, I NEED THE INSTANCE OF THE CURRENT MAINWINDOW HERE.
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainWindowViewModel>();
}
```

MainViewModel:

```
public MainWindowViewModel(Window window)
{
    this.Window = window;

    //Listen out for the window resizing
    this.Window.StateChanged += StateChanged;
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
DataContext="{Binding MainWindow, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

Comment: By the way, you're breaking the whole MVVM concept by providing a view reference to your view model. The view model shouldn't care about views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `Window` to be resolved to your `MainWindow`:

```
public ViewModelLocator()
{
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<System.Windows.Window>(() => System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow);
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
}
```

Also note that you should bind to just "Main" in your XAML:

```
DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

Comment: Many Thanks mm8! This was exactly what i was looking for. Works like a charm now. Finally i understand some more about DI. What you used here is a factory pattern i believe. I have to work on that knowledge. About your second comment. I use configuration over convention so i've named my property within the locator also MainWindow. This was no problem and works fine. Thank you very much for this fast response. I'm happy and i hope you are too :)

Comment: As you can see mm8 i've just upvoted and marked as solved!